# how to modify this php script to handle png and gif uploads

Tags: php, image-processing, png, gif

I have the following script (it looks long, but well commented). Problem is, i get errors when i try to upload a png or gif image. What can i do to adjust this (easy if possible) so that it can either work with png's and gif's or convert them before trying to work with them.

This is the error that i recieve

```
Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg() [function.imagecreatefromjpeg]: gd-jpeg: JPEG library reports unrecoverable error
```

Aparently the first part of the script is working, saving the original upload, but how should i go about this?

```
$idir = "images/";   // Path To Images Directory
$tdir = "images/";   // Path To Thumbnails Directory
$twidth = "125";   // Maximum Width For Thumbnail Images
$theight = "100";   // Maximum Height For Thumbnail Images 


$url = $_FILES['imagefile']['name'];   // Set $url To Equal The Filename For Later Use
  if ($_FILES['imagefile']['type'] == "image/jpg" || $_FILES['imagefile']['type'] == "image/jpeg" || $_FILES['imagefile']['type'] == "image/pjpeg" || $_FILES['imagefile']['type'] == "image/png" || $_FILES['imagefile']['type'] == "image/gif") {
    $file_ext = strrchr($_FILES['imagefile']['name'], '.');   // Get The File Extention In The Format Of , For Instance, .jpg, .gif or .php
        $fdate = date( 'ssU' );
        $copy = copy($_FILES['imagefile']['tmp_name'], "$idir" . $fdate . "$file_ext");   // Move Image From Temporary Location To Permanent Location
    if ($copy) {   // If The Script Was Able To Copy The Image To It's Permanent Location
      print 'Image uploaded successfully.<br />';   // Was Able To Successfully Upload Image
      $simg = imagecreatefromjpeg("$idir" . "$fdate" . "$file_ext");   // Make A New Temporary Image To Create The Thumbanil From
      $currwidth = imagesx($simg);   // Current Image Width
      $currheight = imagesy($simg);   // Current Image Height
      if ($currheight > $currwidth) {   // If Height Is Greater Than Width
         $zoom = $twidth / $currheight;   // Length Ratio For Width
         $newheight = $theight;   // Height Is Equal To Max Height
         $newwidth = $currwidth * $zoom;   // Creates The New Width
      } else {    // Otherwise, Assume Width Is Greater Than Height (Will Produce Same Result If Width Is Equal To Height)
        $zoom = $twidth / $currwidth;   // Length Ratio For Height
        $newwidth = $twidth;   // Width Is Equal To Max Width
        $newheight = $currheight * $zoom;   // Creates The New Height
      }
      $dimg = imagecreate($newwidth, $newheight);   // Make New Image For Thumbnail
      imagetruecolortopalette($simg, false, 256);   // Create New Color Pallete
      $palsize = ImageColorsTotal($simg);
      for ($i = 0; $i < $palsize; $i++) {   // Counting Colors In The Image
       $colors = ImageColorsForIndex($simg, $i);   // Number Of Colors Used
       ImageColorAllocate($dimg, $colors['red'], $colors['green'], $colors['blue']);   // Tell The Server What Colors This Image Will Use
      }
      imagecopyresized($dimg, $simg, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $currwidth, $currheight);   // Copy Resized Image To The New Image (So We Can Save It)
            $fdate = date( 'ssU' );
            imagejpeg($dimg, "$tdir" . "thumb_" . $fdate . "$file_ext");   // Saving The Image

                $full = "$fdate" . "$file_ext";
                $thumb = "thumb_" . $fdate . "$file_ext";

      imagedestroy($simg);   // Destroying The Temporary Image
      imagedestroy($dimg);   // Destroying The Other Temporary Image
      print 'Image thumbnail created successfully.';   // Resize successful
    } else {
      print '<font color="#FF0000">ERROR: Unable to upload image.</font>';   // Error Message If Upload Failed
    }
  } else {
    print '<font color="#FF0000">ERROR: Wrong filetype (has to be a .jpg or .jpeg. Yours is ';   // Error Message If Filetype Is Wrong
    print $file_ext;   // Show The Invalid File's Extention
    print '.</font>';
  }
```

Any guidance here is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, [imagecreatefromjpeg()](http://php.net/imagecreatefromjpeg) can only create images from... jpegs.  There are sister functions for creating images from other file types, namely [imagecreatefrompng()](http://php.net/imagecreatefrompng) and [imagecreatefromgif()](http://php.net/imagecreatefromgif).

I've added to your code.  Give it a try.  Make sure you see the changes, as I put a `die()` in there in case of an invalid image, which may not be what you want:

```
$url = $_FILES['imagefile']['name'];   // Set $url To Equal The Filename For Later Use
  if ($_FILES['imagefile']['type'] == "image/jpg" || $_FILES['imagefile']['type'] == "image/jpeg" || $_FILES['imagefile']['type'] == "image/pjpeg" || $_FILES['imagefile']['type'] == "image/png" || $_FILES['imagefile']['type'] == "image/gif") {
    $file_ext = strrchr($_FILES['imagefile']['name'], '.');   // Get The File Extention In The Format Of , For Instance, .jpg, .gif or .php
        $fdate = date( 'ssU' );
        $copy = copy($_FILES['imagefile']['tmp_name'], "$idir" . $fdate . "$file_ext");   // Move Image From Temporary Location To Permanent Location
    if ($copy) {   // If The Script Was Able To Copy The Image To It's Permanent Location
      print 'Image uploaded successfully.<br />';   // Was Able To Successfully Upload Image
      $cfunction = 'imagecreatefromjpeg';      
      if ($_FILES['imagefile']['type'] == "image/png") {
        $cfunction = 'imagecreatefrompng';
      } else if ($_FILES['imagefile']['type'] == "image/gif") {
        $cfunction = 'imagecreatefromgif';
      } else {
        die("Invalid image format.");
      }
      $simg = $cfunction("$idir" . "$fdate" . "$file_ext");   // Make A New Temporary Image To Create The Thumbanil From
      $currwidth = imagesx($simg);   // Current Image Width
      $currheight = imagesy($simg);   // Current Image Height
      if ($currheight > $currwidth) {   // If Height Is Greater Than Width
         $zoom = $twidth / $currheight;   // Length Ratio For Width
         $newheight = $theight;   // Height Is Equal To Max Height
         $newwidth = $currwidth * $zoom;   // Creates The New Width
      } else {    // Otherwise, Assume Width Is Greater Than Height (Will Produce Same Result If Width Is Equal To Height)
        $zoom = $twidth / $currwidth;   // Length Ratio For Height
        $newwidth = $twidth;   // Width Is Equal To Max Width
        $newheight = $currheight * $zoom;   // Creates The New Height
      }
      $dimg = imagecreate($newwidth, $newheight);   // Make New Image For Thumbnail
      imagetruecolortopalette($simg, false, 256);   // Create New Color Pallete
      $palsize = ImageColorsTotal($simg);
      for ($i = 0; $i < $palsize; $i++) {   // Counting Colors In The Image
       $colors = ImageColorsForIndex($simg, $i);   // Number Of Colors Used
       ImageColorAllocate($dimg, $colors['red'], $colors['green'], $colors['blue']);   // Tell The Server What Colors This Image Will Use
      }
      imagecopyresized($dimg, $simg, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $currwidth, $currheight);   // Copy Resized Image To The New Image (So We Can Save It)
                $fdate = date( 'ssU' );
                imagejpeg($dimg, "$tdir" . "thumb_" . $fdate . "$file_ext");   // Saving The Image

                        $full = "$fdate" . "$file_ext";
                        $thumb = "thumb_" . $fdate . "$file_ext";

      imagedestroy($simg);   // Destroying The Temporary Image
      imagedestroy($dimg);   // Destroying The Other Temporary Image
      print 'Image thumbnail created successfully.';   // Resize successful
    } else {
      print '<font color="#FF0000">ERROR: Unable to upload image.</font>';   // Error Message If Upload Failed
    }
  } else {
    print '<font color="#FF0000">ERROR: Wrong filetype (has to be a .jpg or .jpeg. Yours is ';   // Error Message If Filetype Is Wrong
    print $file_ext;   // Show The Invalid File's Extention
    print '.</font>';
  }
```

Comment: thank you so much, works perfectly! I really appreciate the time you took to help me with this.